# Strange behavior horizontal scrollview of app when create with VS 2012

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm learning Windows Store App development, I create a simple project with "Grid App" in Visual 2012, after that I run app and see that the Horizontal Scrollbar behavior very strange, see the screenshot:

[image: This is when start application]

[image: But when I use mouse, click on the scrollbar and move it to right, the width of scrollbar was smaller than before]

Anyone see this problem? I try to create the Grid App in VS 2013 and it's work correct, I think it's a bug of VS 2012 right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bug in Vs 2012..this is occur because of virtualization i.e 
listbox or listview not loaded all content when it is loaded first time but when u start to scroll it start to load content ..so as no of content loaded thumb start to become small in size..thats why initially thumb  appear as big and later small when scroll.for example you can visit facebook(vertical scrollviewer).
refer this link for understanding http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx

In winrt default  gridview style ItemsPanel like this ..visit style of gridview (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design)

```
     <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

and ItemsPanelTemplate wrapgrid is inheriated from  VirtualizingPanel  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid

VirtualizingPanel  is used for virtualiztion purpose and as you said it is not in vs 2013 means they haven't used VirtualizingPanel  for itemspanel..

Visit this links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780657.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx

thank you

Comment: Thanks for your respond but why application create with VS 2013 it's not?

Comment: Please read explanation again.hope you will understand..thank you.